# Tomcat started but services.msc says it's not

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I know most of the questions here are tomcat is started but can't access localhost:8080.  Mine is the other way around.  It is stopped but it seems that it is not.

I have tomcat7 and it is started (can access our application) but the icon on the taskbar says it is not.
I checked services.msc also and it says it is stopped.
Task manager shows process tomcatw7*32 is running.
I can also access localhost:8080.

Thanks, any help will do.

Regards,
Francis

Comment: So is the question how to stop Tomcat?

Comment: DId you start it *as a service*, or just via `startup.bat`?

Comment: @downshift - more on "how to display status correctly"

Comment: Well there's your answer. It is running but not as a service. Don't ask me how to fix the taskbar icon because I don't know.

Comment: @EJP - We started tomcat using the icon on the taskbar (right click start). took some time and we noticed it didnt start.  we tried again and it says tomcat already running.  we checked our application and it is indeed running.  not sure why the state says stopped, although it is really running.

Comment: @EJP, thanks for your comment. That pointed me to the right direction.